# How to create a Python List of TensorFlow Variables

Tags: python, list, tensorflow

This seems like it should be such an easy thing but I'm having a little trouble figuring out the syntax behind it.  Basically, I have this code:

```
Weights = []
Weights.append(tf.Variable(tf.random_normal( n_input, Population[sample][0]), 0, 1))
```

It returns the error that an 'int' object is not iterable.  However, I can't for the life of me figure out why it's even trying to iterate over an integer.

Any ideas?  Thank you!

Comment: Oh my lord, I had a missing parenthesis.  Should have been `tf.random_normal( (n_input, Population[sample][0]), 0, 1)`.  That way it gives the shape as `(n_input, Population[sample][0])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in your code comes from `tf.random_normal(shape)`. Here `shape` should be a list like `[n_input, 3]`.

The error raised is `'int' object is not iterable` because Python tries to read `n_input` as a list, and it is an int.

---

Your code should be like:

```py
weights = []
weights.append(tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, Population[sample][0], 0., 1.))
```

Comment: Thank you! I was missing a parenthesis and your comment helped me find that